# Uncategorized error Json-ld

Tags: json, author

```
"author" : {
    "@type" : "Person"
    "name" : "Kunjal Chawhan"
  },
```

I have displayed author description like above. The structured data testing tool, is classifying it as uncategorized error.

What should I do?

Answer (score -1):

```
schemaData={{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "JobPosting",
    hiringOrganization: "Client of Maven Workforce",
    title: _get(data, "title", null),
    baseSalary: "40000",
    datePosted: new Date(data && data.cTime)
      .toLocaleDateString()
      .replace(/\//g, "-"),
    validThrough: new Date(data && data.cTime + 2592000000 * 3)
      .toLocaleDateString()
      .replace(/\//g, "-"),
    description: _get(data, "desc", null),
    educationRequirements: _get(data, "edus[0].level", null),
    employmentType: _get(data, "jobType", null),
    experienceRequirements:
      _get(data, "exp.min", null) +
      " to " +
      _get(data, "exp.max", null) +
      " years",
    industry: "Recruitment / Staffing",
    jobLocation: {
      "@type": "Place",
      address: {
        "@type": "PostalAddress",
        addressLocality:
          _get(data, "loc.country", null) +
          " " +
          _get(data, "loc.city", null),
        streetAddress: _get(data, "loc.street", null),
        postalCode: _get(data, "loc.zipcode", null),
        addressRegion: "IN"
      }
    },
    responsibilities: " 1. Screening resume",
    salaryCurrency: _get(data, "salary.currency", null),
    skills: newSkills && newSkills,
    workHours: _get(data, "workDays", null)
  }}
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow! This does not look like an answer to the question asked. Perhaps you mistakenly posted this here.